# Binding a template to data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind content from an template to data in an Angular application. The template is stored in an html file and contains binding expressions:

```
<div>
    <div class="case-header">
        <h3>Case Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="case-body">
        <div>
            <label>Case Number:</label><div>{{item.CaseNumber}}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label><div>{{item.CandidateName}}</div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The element providing the context and data for the template is a row in an ng-grid. In the function below, I create a new scope to contain the data for the current row. The contents of a template is retrieved from an html file and cached to a property when the controller is constructed. However, the $compile call does not bind the data as I want. The function returns the template markup with the binding expressions still in it. I have tried both styles of binding expression.

```
    $scope.getTooltip = function (row) {
        var scope = $scope.$new();
        scope.item = row.entity;
        var elem = angular.element($scope.template);
        var result = $compile(elem)(scope);
        return result.html();
    };
```

The call to $compile appears to be correct vis the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile), but I guess I must have misunderstood something.

How do I get the data values injected into the template?

**Plunker**

Here's a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/z8vdtOdAmdoY8u1zRlYb/preview) to play with.

Comment: could you share you complete code in plunker or fiddle

Comment: Added and linked above in main article.

Answer (score 1):

The $compile(scope)  returns a reference to original dom element or clone of it so you should append it to some element . I have updated your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qatH4XNKPxjPyicur67T?p=preview so see it working.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay, that works in the simplified Plunker I put up to illustrate the problem and is a good start. However I want the `getTooltip` function to return the bound html template so that I can inject that content by binding to the function name itself. I have updated my original Plunker to show what I mean. Is there any way of forcing Angular to bind the data without appending the compilation results to a DOM object?

Comment: no you have to either make a directive or manually append dom to element to make interpolation work

Comment: Bizarre. Why would they have limited it that way?

Comment: may be you should put this in angular issues on git hub site and they will better explain it

Comment: Ajay, there is a problem with your plunker example. The binding doesn't work if you click the "Bind Template" button twice. What could be the reason?